# Google Cloud Print - Python Code Sample - GaiaLogin returns None

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-print

Anyone got it to work?

https://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/cloudprint/docs/pythonCode.html

GaiaLogin returns None :(

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

I too discovered that the Python sample code is broken. I've written a library ([cloudprinting](https://github.com/bradleyayers/cloudprinting)) to simplify using Google Cloud Print with Python.

Comment: How did you get these credentials? I don't see any Google Cloud Print API listed at the Google API Console. Am I damnly lost?